# how to mock method from calling class using mockito in java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class that calls method from another class to get the report status.

```
Class A {
  private classb b = new classb();
  method x() {
    String xyz =b.method1( parm1, parm2) 
  }
}
```

So, when for Junit test for method x getting null pointer on b.method(). I have created mock for class b and did following

```
Mockito.doReturn(val).when(classbMock).method1(parm1,parm2);
```

Please help how can I mock the class b and get pass it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to mock `b` you'll need to give it to the instance of class A.

There's at least several ways of doing this:

1. Use something like [ReflectionUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html) to poke around in A and change the value of the field
2. Give `A` a constructor that allows you to inject the dependency into `A`
3. Just mock `A.x` and assume that `b` works (because that has it's own unit test)

I'd prefer option 3 (assuming that A is a dependent of the thing under test and not the thing being tested).  For a unit test I only want to mock the immediate dependencies, not all of the transient dependencies.

Comment: I disagree with 3 - in the unit test of A you want to test what A.x() does with the return value of b.method1(), and what it in turn returns - assuming that the example code above is just very simplified (and that in the real world it wouldn't be calling a method and doing nothing with the response)

Comment: Maybe I didn't read things right, but I was imagining there's a class C that we can't see that's under test.  It has a dependency on A.  In that case, I wouldn't want to be mocking out A's dependants, I'd just want to mock A.  I think that's a long winded saying of I agree with you.

Comment: Yeah we do agree :) I interpreted the question as writing a test for A

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ClassA instantiating it's own instance of ClassB, pass the instance of B in via A's constructor (or a setter):

```
public class ClassA {
     public ClassA(ClassB b) {
          this.b = b;
     }
     public void x() {
          String blah = b.method1(parm1, parm2);
     }
}
```

Then in your test, you can pass the mock version of B to the instance of A being tested:

```
ClassB classBMock = mock(ClassB.class);
ClassA a = new ClassA(classBMock);
```

And your real code can pass in the non-mock version of ClassB to A.